# AJAX Request Help for next/previous page

Tags: ajax, jquery, request, jquery-mobile

How do I use AJAX to get the Next/Previous Page(s).

How to call in a browser:

```
page.php?page=1-1
```

or

```
page.php?page=1
```

The return is just text.

Should load pages in this format:

1-1
or
1

When the user clicks the next/previous page button(s) how do I pass that page number to the ajax call and display the results.

Also how do I keep track of what page the user is currently viewing?
And how do I put a max min for pages, like I have 100 pages don't make call for page 101

http://jsfiddle.net/2b8gR/5/

HTML

```
<input id="loadPages" name="loadPages" type="button" value="Next" />
<input id="loadPages" name="loadPages" type="button" value="Previous" /> 
<div id="displayResults" name="displayResults">
</div>
```

JS (This is not working)

```
$("#loadPages").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data:{'page': '1-1'},
        error : function (){ alert('Error'); }, 
        success: function (returnData) {
            alert(returnData);
            $('#displayResults').append(returnData);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your javascript has the following errors: `Error:
Problem at line 11 character 1: Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
}

Problem at line 11 character 1: Missing semicolon.
}
`

Comment: Sry did that fix the error? Firebug is not working in Chrome for me right now, sigh...

Comment: I believe your data field is also screwy. try `data: 'page=1-1'` or `data:{'page': '1-1'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this... Keep a global variable called `currentPage` and simply adjust the page number accordingly.

**LIVE DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/MawSB/

**HTML**

```
<input id="next" type="button" value="Next" />
<input id="prev" type="button" value="Previous" /> 
<div id="displayResults" name="displayResults">Current Page: 1</div>
```

**JS**

```
var currentPage=1;
loadCurrentPage();

$("#next, #prev").click(function(){
    currentPage = 
        ($(this).attr('id')=='next') ? currentPage + 1 : currentPage - 1;

    if (currentPage==0) //Check for min
        currentPage=1;
    else if (currentPage==101) //Check for max
        currentPage=100;
    else
        loadCurrentPage();
});

function loadCurrentPage(){
    $('input').attr('disabled','disabled'); //disable buttons

    //show loading image
    $('#displayResults').html('<img src="http://blog-well.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/indicator-big-2.gif" />'); 

    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: 'html=Current Page: ' + currentPage+'&delay=1',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('input').attr('disabled',''); //re-enable buttons
            $('#displayResults').html(data); //Update Div
        }
    });
}
```

Then your php page can access `$_REQUEST['page'];` and return data accordingly.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, doesn't seem to be working with JQM jQuery Mobile. And looking at the requests I don't see the page parameter being appended in the request

Comment: try removing the data field and making the url read `url: 'page.php?page=' + currentPage,`

Comment: yeah tried that, still nothing returned but I see the request

Comment: does the page that the url points to `page.php?page=1` work if you navigate to it manually?

Comment: it's almost working except it appends the data instead of replaces the data

Comment: it should replace all of the HTML in the div called `displayResults`. that's what the `.html()` function does.