# How do I prevent a link from adding to the history stack with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery mobile, I am using a list view with a previous and next links for pagination.  Everything works fine, but I do not want the prev and next pages to add to the history stack.  The idea is that hitting back will just go to the actual previous page.

The only thing I have found to do this is to add data-rel="dialog" to the a tags, but I don't want it to be a pop-up dialog.

Otherwise I tried to add

```
$.mobile.nonHistorySelectors="dialog,pagination"
```

to the mobileinit event, with the attribute data-rel="pagination" added to the a tag.  But this only throws errors when the links are clicked (the error also occurs even without the nonHistorySelectors added to the mobileinit event).

**EDIT:**

The closest thing I have found is this JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".page-prev").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {changeHash:false, reverse:true});
    });

    $(".page-next").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {changeHash:false});
    });
</script>
```

and this HTML

```
<a href="/blog?page=1" class="page-prev" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Prev</a>
<a href="/blog?page=3" class="page-next" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
```

This seems to do well to keep the browsers history from being updated, but sometimes when click next the pages sliding around will do some funky things, such as loading/sliding twice.  Plus one thing that it fails to do is that if I were to navigate to a page from here and come back, it will be back at page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and it should be fine:

```
 // Fix for back buttons
    $(document).on('vclick', '[data-rel=back]', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        // $.mobile.back(e);
        var back = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
        $.mobile.changePage(back, {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true,
            changeHash: false
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism to delete silently anything from browsing history.

You should use AJAX to populate your list.
And so your links will look like `<a href="javascript:renderNextPage()">`

Comment: I am not able to do this because I am only overriding the display and I am not adding functionality.  So no partial loading.

Comment: While there's no mechanism to delete from history, JQM loads via AJAX and pushes to the browser history. It would be nice if JQM had a mechanism to prevent this for either loaded pages or the links loading them. Consider the situation where a server will redirect to a login form, the login form should not be part of history and it is not known when this may occur (on session timeout etc..), so it would be nice to have `<div data-role='page' data-inhistory='false'>`

Answer (score 1):

Does it work to add `data-rel="back"` to the anchor tag?

This is the solution suggested on the jQuery Mobile demo documentation, under 'Back linking'.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, My solution was to split up the site navigation and the pagination navigation into two separate navigation menus. So I have the header navigation with the site navigation and would add the next/prev navigation buttons to the page: [AJAX Request Help for next/previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278374/ajax-request-help-for-next-previous-page)

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/MawSB/

UPDATE:

Here is a fast example of what I mean:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/trdYP/26/

JS:

```
var currentPage=1;
loadCurrentPage();

$("#next, #prev").click(function(){
    currentPage= ($(this).attr('id')=='next') ? currentPage + 1 : currentPage - 1;

    if (currentPage==0) 
        currentPage=1;
    else if (currentPage==101) 
        currentPage=100;
    else
        loadCurrentPage();
});

function loadCurrentPage(){
    //$('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#displayResults').html('<img src="http://blog-well.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/indicator-big-2.gif" />');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: 'html=Current Page: ' + currentPage+'&delay=1',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
           // $('input').attr('disabled','');
            $('#displayResults').html(data);
        }
    });

    $('#home').page();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li> 
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li> 
        </ul> 
        <input id="next" type="button" value="Next" />
        <input id="prev" type="button" value="Previous" /> 
        <div id="displayResults" name="displayResults">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page 2</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I unfortunately cannot do any more than load the next page whole, and not partially.

Comment: The page number is in the URL. I am basically using a listview for blog posts.  There is no set number of pages.  Oh and I edited the above with some other thing I have tried.

Comment: This is a fine method if I were starting over, but here I am trying to bootstrap an existing navigation paradigm.  Each pagination is its own request and it's own URL.

Comment: @Tyler Clendenin: As I said in my answer already - there is no mechanism to do what you want. As soon as you navigate to other page it gets to the history. Dot.

Answer (score 0):

The data-rel attr has worked for me

```
<a data-rel="dialog" ...
```

As per the documentation

Link
Links, including those with a data-role="button", and form submit buttons share these attributes

**data-rel**    back (to move one step back in history)

**dialog** (to open link styled as dialog, not tracked in history)

**external** (for linking to another domain)

https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html