# Non-ajax tab bar with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, tabs

I am trying to create a page with two tabs. I put a navbar into the footer area and by clicking the buttons on the navbar I can navigate between pages but this is far from being optimal for our scenario. If the user switches between the tabs multiple times, the browser saves all the history for these navigation activities and the user has to tap back button several times to return to home screen. Yes I know I can put a Back button to the header and return the user to the home screen with a single tap but handling the back button issue is more important right now.

Is there a way to create a tab bar that doesn't switch pages asynchronously? All I need is a navbar that hides or shows the content when one of the buttons are clicked. Or should I hide or show inner content manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using a mutli-page template, it should work to use the `data-ajax='false'` attribute.  This will prevent JQM from placing that in the history as you are experiencing.

Also, check out this similar post for how to stop pages from being added to history: [How do I prevent a link from adding to the history stack with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819027/how-do-i-prevent-a-link-from-adding-to-the-history-stack-with-jquery-mobile) - there are helpful answers on there (while not accepted by OP).

Cheers!